# Remove commits that are not connected to the branch

Tags: git

I wanted to merge in some changes from another repo so I added the remote, fetched and merged.
But I did not think that the commits of the other branch would be added.

I backed one commit from my merge and manually added the changed files and pushed that commit.

So now I have two disconnected commit trees in one branch.
Something like this:

```
A-B-C-D-master
1-2-3-4
```

And I just want to remove the 1-2-3-4 commits. I don't care about history or any child/parent commits or the files.
I want to keep the A-B-C-D commits with all history.

I have tried:

```
git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now --all
git gc --prune=all --aggressive

git rebase [hash]
```

But nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If no ref points to `1`, `2`, `3` and `4`, they are dangling and will be removed by `gc`.
Where do you still see those commits?
Do still some heads or tags point to those commits?

Comment: Yes of course I forgot to remove the tags. Now gc works just fine. Thanks!

Comment: Also worked for me once I looked for tags as well as branches.